# KUbuntu desktop weirdness

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde

I use Kubuntu 14.04, and have it configured to use/display the /home/xxxx/Desktop folder in a "folder" layout. The problem is, I often use the desktop folder for downloads/temporary working directory for files, but anything new I copy to the folder, I can see just fine if I look at the folder with dolphin, but these files are invisible ON the actual KDE desktop. I see all of the linked *.desktop files for the icons I keep on the desktop, but not the documents/files I put there later.. Not sure WHY this is, as I also have KUbuntu configured the same way (I think) on my laptop and everything works as expected there..

Comment: Stupid question: do you have a desktop folder panel added to your desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your question if you're already doing this, but in case not...

Right click on the desktop, select "Default Desktop Settings" -> View, and in the first combo box change "Default Desktop" to "Folder View"

Comment: yes, thats the way the system *is* configured. I see everything in the desktop folder from dolphin, but only see the icons actually *on* the desktop...

Comment: Further investigation shows that if I either reboot or logout/login, *everything* in the /home/xxx/Desktop folder appears on the desktop.. But new folders/docs added to it *after* the reboot/logout/in do not show up...